# Image Fonts with MvvmCross binding

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on a mobile app (for android and ios) using mvvmcross w/ xamarin.  There is a screen where the users want to use their custom images for numbers 0-9, for a numeric field.  For example if the number is 123, there would be 3 images on the screen, an image for 1, for 2, and 3.  What would be the best way to wire up the solution for this?

Off the top of my head I am thinking the following:

1) Encourage them to use text stylings instead of custom images.  The issue here is that a legacy version of the app already exists and uses the images.  They might have spent a lot of time on those images and may be dead set on using them.  Still if it is a bad practice and I can do something similar with styles, I wouldn't be opposed to trying to sway them this direction.  The images have a gradient shadowing that I'm guessing would be hard to duplicate.

2) Use an image for each digit.  Use a custom converter to convert the digit (0-9) to the corresponding image.  So the model would contain Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, etc.  Hide digits that don't apply (ie shorter numbers).  I'm not sure of the feasibility of this, or how I would deal with hiding elements, or handling things such as if the padding needs to be different based on the number.

3) Do everything completely on the UI side of things.  It's been done before on the native app so I believe this is doable.  I just need to implement it using C# instead of objective C, and would need to implement it twice (once on IoS, once on Android).

Comment: I'm viewing custom controls N+1 demo and am leaning towards creating a custom FrameLayout contains multiple ImageViews (one for each digit).
http://slodge.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/n18-android-custom-controls-n1-days-of.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the important thing here is that 'the app is king'

The general app approach is to let the User Experience to drive the technology choice - and often you operate a 'no compromise' policy on User Experience!

(Obviously though, sometimes there can be a little compromise when costs start to escalate).

I think all 3 of your options could work.

Personally I suspect I might go for your 3rd option - drawing a custom data-bound view provides the most flexibilty and the most native solution for your app. For more on custom data-bound views see N=18 and N=19 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

- An Android custom data-bound `View` - http://slodge.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/n18-android-custom-controls-n1-days-of.html
- An iOS custom data-bound `UIView` - http://slodge.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/n19-custom-controls-on-ios-n1-days-of.html

I think these custom controls could easily reuse your number images, and would be fairly easy to size, animate, etc. - in order to provide the beautiful app experience your customer is looking for.